# Intermittent ClassCastException with MutableLiveData in Unit Tests

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-testing, mockk

In my ViewModel I have a `MutableLiveData` source which I update with the visibility for an item in my UI. When I write a unit test for this function, I end up getting a `ClassCastException` on my `MutableLiveData`. Not exactly sure why I'm getting this exception because I'm using `postValue` to update the value in my LiveData. I'm not re-assigning the MutableLiveData anywhere.

This is what my ViewModel code looks like.

```kotlin
private val _fabVisibility = MutableLiveData<Int>(getFabVisibility())
val fabVisibility: LiveData<Int> = _fabVisibility

fun updateInformation(lat: Double, lng: Double, zoom: Double = myRepo.currentZoom ?: 10.0) {
    ...
    // ^^^ some other logic
    myRepo.currentZoom = zoom
    _fabVisibility.postValue(getFabVisibility())
}

private fun getFabVisibility(): Int {
    return when (myRepo.currentZoom ?: 10.0 >= ZOOM_THRESHOLD) {
        true -> View.VISIBLE
        false -> View.GONE
    }
}
```

This is what my unit test for this function looks like. I'm using MockK.
I do have the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` added on my test class so the values are immediately available on the LiveData I have in my ViewModel.

```kotlin
@Rule
@JvmField
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Test
fun updateUsersLocationInformation() = runBlocking {
    vm.updateUsersLocationInformation(42.5, -83.4, 12.0)

    assertEquals(vm.fabVisibility.value, View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Here's what the stack trace looks like. Sometimes this test appears to run fine, but then other times I end up with this exception being thrown.

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

    at com.some.generic.packageName.view.viewModel.DingusViewModel.getFabVisibility(DingusViewModel.kt:209)
    at com.some.generic.packageName.view.viewModel.DingusViewModel.updateInformation(DingusViewModel.kt:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.MethodCall.call(MethodCall.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.SelfCallEliminatorCallable.call(SelfCallEliminatorCallable.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:83)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.access$handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:20)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1$invocation$$inlined$stdFunctions$lambda$1.invoke(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:28)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub$handleInvocation$originalPlusToString$1.invoke(MockKStub.kt:227)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.SpyKStub.defaultAnswer(SpyKStub.kt:15)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:263)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:20)
    at com.some.generic.packageName.view.viewModel.DingusViewModel.updateInformation(DingusViewModel.kt:205)
    at com.some.generic.packageName.view.viewModel.DingusViewModelTest$updateInformation$1.invokeSuspend(DingusViewModelTest.kt:683)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.some.generic.packageName.view.viewModel.DingusViewModelTest.updateInformation(DingusViewModelTest.kt:679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the mocked  `myRepo.currentZoom`.  If you mock it, check the returned value is right.

Comment: how are you mocking and stubing the repo class?

Comment: @iamanbansal This is how I'm stubbing the repo
`val myRepo: MyRepo = mockk(relaxed = true)`

Comment: @esentsov When I add a few `println` to see values, `currentZoom` shows what I previously set it to in the other function